# Using Lodash Merge array, Why result duplicate array value?, Where wrong my code?

Tags: javascript, lodash

My code

```
var result = [];

var datax = [{
    "tag": "TH000144"
}, {
    "tag": "TH000147"
}, {
    "tag": "TH000166"
}, {
    "tag": "TH000169"
}, {
    "tag": "TH000170"
}];

var newdatax = [{
    "serial": "14563",
    "tag": "TH000144"
}, {
    "serial": "7777",
    "tag": "TH000147"
}, {
    "tag": "TH000169",
    "serial": null
}];

var result = lodash.merge(datax, newdatax);
```

result

```
[{
    "tag": "TH000144",
    "serial": "14563"
}, {
    "tag": "TH000147",
    "serial": "7777"
}, {
    "tag": "TH000169",
    "serial": null
}, {
    "tag": "TH000169"
}, {
    "tag": "TH000170"
}]
```

I need like this

```
[{
    "tag": "TH000144",
    "serial": "14563"
}, {
    "tag": "TH000147",
    "serial": "7777"
}, {
    "tag": "TH000169",
    "serial": null
}, {
    "tag": "TH000166"
}, {
    "tag": "TH000170"
}]
```

Where my code is wrong?

Comment: You don't want `{"serial": "14563","tag": "TH000144"}`?

Comment: No. My result duplicate {"tag": "TH000169"}, {"tag": "TH000169", "serial": null}, But I need {"tag": "TH000166"} replace {"tag": "TH000169"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reverse the arguments of merge, like `_.merge(newdatax, datax);`

my take on what went wrong:

when the recursive merge function reached `TH000169`, it resolved to undefined; seems very likely due to `null` value of serial. The docs mention this potential hangup [HERE](https://lodash.com/docs#merge). the documentation also suggests it should take the form  `_.merge(destination, source);`.

```
var result = [];

var datax = [{
    "tag": "TH000144"
}, {
    "tag": "TH000147"
}, {
    "tag": "TH000166"
}, {
    "tag": "TH000169"
}, {
    "tag": "TH000170"
}];

var newdatax = [{
    "serial": "14563",
    "tag": "TH000144"
}, {
    "serial": "7777",
    "tag": "TH000147"
}, {
    "tag": "TH000169",
    "serial": null
}];

var result = _.merge(newdatax, datax);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
```

result

```
[
    {
        "serial": "14563",
        "tag": "TH000144"
    },
    {
        "serial": "7777",
        "tag": "TH000147"
    },
    {
        "tag": "TH000166",
        "serial": null
    },
    {
        "tag": "TH000169"
    },
    {
        "tag": "TH000170"
    }
]
```